# Type 'typeof class' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to use react native navigation using typescript and I am getting a `Type 'typeof LoginScreen' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<any>'` error when trying to connect my screens.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  }
}
```

This fails at component={LoginScreen}. 
I understand that it is because my React component 'HomeScreen' isn't expecting any props, however what is the safe way of handling this issue, as I saw many different solutions.

Comment: i think you have to pass type props to your component like React.Component<someProps, someState>, someProps can act as an interface.

Comment: I understand that but how exactly would I go about it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. You can use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/navigation-prop/ which has documentation on how to handle this exact case. Hope this helps some people.

Comment: Share some more light, was not able to follow the link..